# How to get an elements class name if ithe div was declared as '''<div id 'one' class="element one"></div>'''?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 3 elements one, two, three, declared precisely as follows:

```
<div id =container>
  <div id 'one' class="element one"></div> 
  <div id 'two' class="element two"></div>
  <div id 'three' class="element three"></div>
</div>
```

Using the next statements initially:

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element");
```

I want to use console.log to print the elements class for each one of them.
So far all I managed to do is this

```
elements.forEach((elem, i) => {
  console.log(elem.id);
});
```

How can I get the name of the class of each element as 'one', 'two', 'three'?

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element");

elements.forEach((elem, i) => {
  console.log(elem.id);
});
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div id 'one' class="element one"></div>
  <div id 'two' class="element two"></div>
  <div id 'three' class="element three"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `elem.className`, or to get them as an array `elem.classList`

Answer (score 0):

Use elem.className to get classes.

```
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element");

elements.forEach((elem, i) => {
  console.log(elem.className);
});
```